# Link Local Address and DHCP

Tags: networking, dhcp, link-local

If a networking device has attained Link Local Address and attains a Link Local Address - say - 169.254.111.135. Now if DHCP got enabled in the device and it acquires an IP from DHCP server in network - should the device give away Link Local Address?

What is the ideal situation in such a case for the device to do?

Answer (score 3):

Is defined on RFC 3927 section 1.9:

> If a host finds that an interface that was previously configured with an IPv4 Link-Local address now has an operable routable address available, the host MUST use the routable address when initiating new communications, and MUST cease dvertising the availability of the IPv4 Link-Local address through whatever mechanisms that address had been made known to others.  The host SHOULD continue to use the IPv4 Link-Local         address for communications already underway, and MAY continue to accept new communications addressed to the IPv4 Link-Local address.  Ways in which an operable routable address might become available on an interface include:
>
> - Manual configuration
> - Address assignment through DHCP
> - Roaming of the host to a network on which a previously assigned address becomes operable

So yes, if the device gets assigned a DHCP address then Link Local one should be dropped. Check https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927#section-1.9

Answer (score 2):

For IPv4, it is usual to drop the Link Local Address when an IP address is obtained by another means.  Once you have attained a different IP address the Link Local Address doesn't have much use.

For IPv6, the Link Local Address is retained.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Please confirm the state when Link Local Address needs to be dropped - when we send DHCP Discover or receive DHCP offer - I am not sure what's the Link Local RFC states?

Comment: Can you please provide some references of how to test Link Local addressing method - I mean how Link Local addressing method should behave the RFC 3927 is cryptic to conclude the test cases